# How can I define the saturation function in Matlab?

Tags: control, matlab

I would like to write a Matlab code for an angular velocity of this type:

$\omega=\omega_{fb}+sat(\omega_{ff})$

where $\omega_{fb}$ is a feedback angular velocity and $\omega_{ff}$ is a feedforward angular velocity.

As you can see, the feedforward term has been saturated.

The problem is that there is not a saturation function in Matlab. Moreover, I would like to do this inside a Matlab function block, and not use the saturation block of Simulink.

I have heard that some use the atan() function to perform the saturation, but I am not sure I can do this.

So, my question is:

How can I define the saturation function in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always employ conditional expressions that are clear and explicit.
Instead, if you like compact forms, you may implement saturation as below:

```matlab
w = w_fb + min(hi, max(low, w_ff));
```

where `hi` and `low` are the upper and lower bounds of the saturation.